# Cant print my last node in linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Im doing a project that creates a linked list to form two polynomials, then gives the user the option to do math operations with the lists. I've gotten to the point where i'm reading my list in, and using stack to order it properly. Then I wanted to make sure my list was being read in properly and so far so good, EXCEPT my tail end isn't being read in. Or maybe its my syntax on my while loop?

```
import java.util.*;

public class IntegerNode {

    private int coefficient;
    private int exponent;
    private IntegerNode next;

    public IntegerNode() {
        coefficient = 0;
        exponent = 1;
        next = null;
    }

    public IntegerNode(int c, int e) {
        coefficient = c;
        exponent = e;
        next = null;
    }

    public IntegerNode(int c, int e, IntegerNode n) {
        coefficient = c;
        exponent = e;
        next = n;
    }

    public void setCoefficient(int newCoefficient) {
        coefficient = newCoefficient;
    }

    public void setExponent (int newExponent) {
        exponent = newExponent;
    }

    public int getExponent() {
        return exponent;
    }//end getItem

    public int getCoefficient() {
        return coefficient;
    }//end getItem

    public void SetNext (IntegerNode nextNode) {
        next = nextNode;
    }//end setNext

    public IntegerNode getNext () {
        return next;
    }//end getNext

}//end class IntegerNode

class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //First polynomial:
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter coefficient: ");
    int coeff = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter exponent: ");
    int exp = sc.nextInt();
    Stack<IntegerNode> p1 = new Stack<IntegerNode>();
    IntegerNode n = new IntegerNode(coeff, exp);
    p1.push(n);
    while (exp != 0){
        System.out.println("Enter coefficient: ");
        coeff = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter exponent: ");
        exp = sc.nextInt();
        IntegerNode m = new IntegerNode(coeff, exp);
        p1.push(m);           
    }

    IntegerNode tail = p1.pop();
    IntegerNode head = null;
    while(!p1.empty()){
        head = p1.pop();
        head.SetNext(tail);
        System.out.println(head.getCoefficient() + " to " + tail.getCoefficient());
        tail = head;
    }

    IntegerNode cur = tail;
    while(!(cur.getNext()).equals(null)){
        System.out.println(cur.getCoefficient()+" "+cur.getExponent());
        System.out.println("NEXTNODE: " + cur.getNext().getCoefficient());
        cur = cur.getNext();
    }
    //Read in two integers, check each time if exponent is zero
    //create linked list in reverse order of input
    //Use stack to create LIFO list



    //Repeat above, but for second polynomial

    //Prompt user to choose which operation
    //Prompt user to specify what order if subtracted

    //iterate through p1
    //for every element in p1:
    //iterate through p2 and see if that element matches the current element
    //in p1. If so, then add their coefficients
    //Store results as you go
    //Output the results and indicate what operation was done


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Driver.main(IntegerNode.java:85)
```

That would be at my last while loop. Any ideas?

Comment: I just want to note that I can read values in just fine, until I get to my exponent value being 0. Then I receive that error. For instance I will do 10, 2 then 9, 1 then 8,0. The first 2 nodes will get printed, then it will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(!(cur.getNext()).equals(null))
```

instead of above try this once:

```
while(!(cur.getNext())==null)
```

You can never call the .equals() method on an object reference that is null. It is a method, just like the rest, so if the object reference is truly null it will just throw a NullPointerException.

Try this :

```
do{

} while(((cur.getNext())!=null))
```

Comment: I gave it a quick try, and the compiler is saying your ! operand is a bad operand type. Which is interested because all we did was remove the .equals, maybe we needed while((cur.getNext())!=null) ?

Comment: Yes, try that once, what you wrote in your comment.

Comment: Yep, have to move that operand around :) It finishes the iteration, but doesn't print my last node >:(

Comment: Ah.. It just popped into my head. You are awesome

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you're doing this:

```
IntegerNode tail = p1.pop();
```

... you should make sure that there is something to pop.

Second, this:

```
while(!(cur.getNext()).equals(null))
```

...is what probably causing your problem.  You're doing a comparison with a `null` object.  Can't do that.  Use this:

```
while(cur.getNext() != null)
```

As far as printing your last value, well, you get your last node and then you're out of them, so you're never going to print what was on the last node.  I'd use `do{}while()`.

Comment: Hmm.. I do a p1.push(m) which should be my node object to pop.. was that not how I was supposed to push?

Comment: @EddieGbo Is that regarding the first comment?  It's just wise to protect yourself from popping `null`.

Comment: And you are awesome too ! Yes it was regarding to your first comment. I thought I was popping what I was pushing when id say p1.push(m)